# How do I know if my MacBook Pro supports SATA III?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, ssd, macbook, sata

I have a MacBook Pro that I bought around 2011.  How do I know what level of SATA the internal hard drive interface supports?

This is the About This Mac:

[image]

And this is what the SATA section of the System Report looks like.

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can take a look at the **Link Speed** under the **Intel 5 Series Chipset** section.
SATA levels are named after a number (1, 2, 3) and also for their speeds.

- SATA 1.0 is known as SATA 1.5Gb/s
- SATA 2.0 is known as SATA 3.0Gb/s === Your computer supports SATA 2.0
- SATA 3.0 is known as SATA 6.0Gb/s

"Link speeds are the theoretical maximum speed at which data can transfer to or from those devices."
- Taken from [here.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73399/what-is-an-ssd-drives-negotiated-link-speed)

The "Negotiated Link Speed" is what you currently have, in your case, this is SATA 2.0 too…

Here is a link with a description of the different SATA [revisions](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/global/html/about/whitepaper02.html)

Comment: What about this: https://www.flickr.com/photos/130118503@N02/17211329902
Link speed: 6 Gb/s, Negotiated link speed: 3 Gb/s. It's SATA 2 or 3?

Answer (score 2):

It really supports any SATA version I, II, or III. The SATA drives and are backwards compatible. If the drive is SATA III and your MB Pro is SATA II, the dive will perform at the theoretical levels of a SATA II drive. Same for SATA I.

Comment: So, not only controllers are backward compatible, but the drives too?

Comment: Yes. You can combine any combination of SATA{1,2,3} drives and SATA{1,2,3} controller. The used speed will be the lowest shared one though. (E.g. a SATA-III drive on a SATA-1 controller will work with a link speed it 1.5Gb/sec).